# Which version of raspi can I use for .NET remote debugging?

Tags: .net, .net-core, raspberry-pi, omnisharp

I struggling to figure out which raspi dotnet remote debugging works on.

There's [an issue on omnisharp discussing issues with ARM v7](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2771).

I have a Raspi 4 and `cat /proc/cpuinfo` tells me (first 3 cores omitted):

```
...
processor : 3
model name : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS : 270.00
Features : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part : 0xd08
CPU revision : 3



Hardware : BCM2711
Revision : c03114
Serial : 10000000eca61694
Model : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
```

So I have indeed a v7.

But according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi), Pi 4 should have ARMv8, but that seems not to be the case.

What's going on? Which raspi do I need?

.NET version is 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi4 (any version) is just fine. Even a Pi3 works. You are right that the Pi4 is ARMv8 (64 bit) but the default Raspbian that most people still use is a 32 bit operating system. A 64 bit version is available, but currently in beta. The 32 Bit Raspbian is incorrectly reporting the CPU as ARMv7 for compatibility reasons.

That post you have found there is very old and is about .NET Core 2.1. The current version is .NET 6.0, which has full support for remote debugging on 32-Bit ARM CPUs. Even .NET 5.0 works fine.